# What is the difference between Debian's LXQT installation packages: lxqt-core, lxqt and task-lxqt-desktop?

Tags: debian, lxqt

I want to install LXQT Desktop Environment on my Debian. What is the difference between lxqt-core, lxqt and task-lxqt-desktop apt packages available through Debian's official repository?

[Debian's wiki on lxqt](https://wiki.debian.org/LXQt) tell us how to install them but don't explain their differences and how should we choose one.

Answer (score 4):

[lxqt-core](https://packages.debian.org/buster/lxqt-core) is the lightest one.
It works out of the box if you already have another desktop environment installed.
If not, you should also install a display manager such as SDDM or LightDM. (apt install lightdm)

[lxqt](https://packages.debian.org/buster/lxqt) is the default version, lxqt-core is one of its dependencies. It comes with a display manager (it prompts you which one you want) so it should work out of the box. Also comes with some other optional packages. Some of them may be intresting/important to you but probably not all of them.

[task-lxqt-desktop](https://packages.debian.org/buster/task-lxqt-desktop) is the heaviest. lxqt is one of its dependencies. It comes with SDDM, libreoffice, hunspell (spellchecker), tasksel and synaptic (the GUI package manager).